# Different behaviour between Flex mx:XMLList and fx:XMLList

Tags: apache-flex, mxml

Having this code in a flex3 project worked (note the enabled property on the sixth item):

```
    <mx:XMLList id="items">
            <menuitem label="file">
                <menuitem label="file.new" data="New"/>
                <menuitem label="file.saveAs" data="SaveAs"/>
                <menuitem label="file.open" data="Open"/>
                <menuitem label="file.close" data="Close"/>
            </menuitem>
            <menuitem label="business">
                <menuitem label="business.add" data="AddBusiness"/>
                <menuitem label="business.delete" enabled="{someproperty.selected}" data="DeleteBusiness"/>
            </menuitem>
            <menuitem label="help">
                <menuitem label="help.about" data="About" />
            </menuitem>
        </mx:XMLList>
```

However fx:XMLList can't handle binding in that way. This code gives a compilation error:

```
        <fx:XMLList id="items">
            <menuitem label="file">
                <menuitem label="file.new" data="New"/>
                <menuitem label="file.saveAs" data="SaveAs"/>
                <menuitem label="file.open" data="Open"/>
                <menuitem label="file.close" data="Close"/>
            </menuitem>
            <menuitem label="business">
                <menuitem label="business.add" data="AddBusiness"/>
                <menuitem label="business.delete" enabled="{someproperty.selected}" data="DeleteBusiness"/>
            </menuitem>
            <menuitem label="help">
                <menuitem label="help.about" data="About" />
            </menuitem>
        </fx:XMLList>
```

1120: Access of undefined property items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are compiling your project in strict mode and that you are using the *items* XMLList directly as `dataProvider` for some component (at least it was the only way I've found to reproduce the problem), like this:

```
<s:List>
    <s:dataProvider>
        <s:XMLListCollection>
            <fx:XMLList id="items">
                <menuitem label="file">
                    <menuitem label="file.new" data="New"/>
                    <menuitem label="file.saveAs" data="SaveAs"/>
                    <menuitem label="file.open" data="Open"/>
                    <menuitem label="file.close" data="Close"/>
                </menuitem>
                <menuitem label="business">
                    <menuitem label="business.add" data="AddBusiness"/>
                    <menuitem label="business.delete" enabled="{someproperty.selected}" data="DeleteBusiness"/>
                </menuitem>
                <menuitem label="help">
                    <menuitem label="help.about" data="About"/>
                </menuitem>
            </fx:XMLList>
        </s:XMLListCollection>
    </s:dataProvider>
</s:List>
```

This reproduces the same error (#1120) you mentioned. In order to fix this, you have to declare the XMLList prior to its container (in the example it's a `List`), in the `<fx:Declarations>` block. This way you are assuring that the *items* reference will exist before the container is created, which is what strict mode verifies during compilation.

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <fx:XMLList id="items">
        <menuitem label="file">
            <menuitem label="file.new" data="New"/>
            <menuitem label="file.saveAs" data="SaveAs"/>
            <menuitem label="file.open" data="Open"/>
            <menuitem label="file.close" data="Close"/>
        </menuitem>
        <menuitem label="business">
            <menuitem label="business.add" data="AddBusiness"/>
            <menuitem label="business.delete" enabled="{someproperty.selected}" data="DeleteBusiness"/>
        </menuitem>
        <menuitem label="help">
            <menuitem label="help.about" data="About"/>
        </menuitem>
    </fx:XMLList>
</fx:Declarations>

<s:List>
    <s:dataProvider>
        <s:XMLListCollection source="{ items }"/>
    </s:dataProvider>
</s:List>
```

**Update:** This will also generate the #1120 error if you don't have the compiler's strict mode option enabled. Just declare the XMLList in the `<fx:Declarations>` block and it should work fine.